# Python read comma separated txt file having thousands separator

Tags: python, pandas

My comma separated txt file contains data in the following format (of course, there are more columns and rows).

```
1977,PA,2017-08-07,55,New Firms,327.0
1978,NY,2017-08-07,45,New Firms,$30,127
1978,NY,2017-08-07,$10,000,New Firms,1,000
```

As you can see, some data contain thousands separator and I read like this:

```
df=pd.read_csv("data.txt", thousands=r',')
df.head()
```

This gives an error message

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 13 fields in line 102996, saw 14
```

I think the error occurs because some data contain thousands separators.

Any suggestions?

Comment: A quick fix would be to just use `.split(", ")`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your suggestion?

Answer (score 4):

Try with this

```
df=pd.read_csv("text.csv", sep=', ',header =None,names=['colA','colB','colC','colD','colE','colF'])

df.head()
```

it outputs:

```
Out[25]: 
   colA colB        colC     colD       colE     colF
0  1977   PA  2017-08-07       55  New Firms    327.0
1  1978   NY  2017-08-07       45  New Firms  $30,127
2  1978   NY  2017-08-07  $10,000  New Firms    1,000
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe an extra `sep` argument:

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.txt", sep = ', ', header = None, thousands = ',')
```